# How to find and replace between characters

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to replace the second "AND" by "OR" in the following string:

`country == "BR" AND (leftHour >= 6 AND rightHour < 24)`

My strategy is to do this with regex : `\((.*)\)`
But this matches all characters between brackets and I just want to match the `AND`between the two brackets.

In Go would be perfect, but the good regex could suffice.

Edit : The string is not fixed and we can have multiple "AND" before like, example : 
`currency == "USD" AND country == "BR" AND (leftHour >= 6 AND rightHour < 24)`

Comment: Try replacing `.*` with `AND` in your regexp.

Comment: I tried but this is not working.. https://regex101.com/r/RaKxXP/3/

Comment: My bad, does this work for you? https://regex101.com/r/RaKxXP/4

Comment: Perfect ! You can post the answer and I will accept it :) Thanks a lot

Comment: the existing answers are equally good, if not better, you can go ahead a mark one of them.

Comment: You're a good guy :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a regex like `\([^()]*\)` to match strings inside innermost parentheses and use [`ReplaceAllStringFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAllStringFunc) to only replace all `AND` with `OR` inside the matched texts:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"
        "regexp"
)

func main() {
        input := `country == "BR" AND (leftHour >= 6 AND rightHour < 24)`
        r := regexp.MustCompile(`\([^()]*\)`)
        fmt.Println(r.ReplaceAllStringFunc(input, func(m string) string {
                return strings.ReplaceAll(m, "AND", "OR")
        }))
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/sfwQo64R0Dr)

Note you may replace `AND` using a second regex:

```
return regexp.MustCompile(`\bAND\b`).ReplaceAllString(m, "OR")
```

that will replace `AND` that are whole words regardless of whether there is a space or not. See [this Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/SwxmOigExpv).